# Can you start a new TCP server from within a running TCP server?

Tags: sockets, tcp, elixir

I'm doing a kind of odd experiment with Elixir. (Maybe it's not odd, but I haven't done it before.)

I'm trying to set up a TCP server that can trigger other TCP servers based on some input. This isn't going into production anywhere - just trying to see what's possible. I'm not super familiar with TCP.

The first server starts fine, but my code throws this error when I try to type something like "PORT 9000" into the first server (via telnet):

```
FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :inet_tcp.getserv/1
    (kernel) inet_tcp.erl:55: :inet_tcp.getserv("9000")
    (kernel) gen_tcp.erl:190: :gen_tcp.listen/2
    (gen_tcp) lib/tcp_server.ex:11: TcpServer.init/1
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Here is the code:

```
defmodule TcpServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(port) do
    ip = Application.get_env :tcp_server, :ip, {127,0,0,1}
    port = Application.get_env :tcp_server, :port, port
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,[ip,port],[])
  end

  def init [ip,port] do
    {:ok, listen_socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(port,[:binary, {:packet, 0}, {:active, true}, {:ip, ip}])
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.accept listen_socket
    {:ok, %{ip: ip, port: port, socket: socket}}
  end

  def handle_info({ :tcp, socket, packet }, state) do
    # Expects something like "PORT 3456"
    if packet =~ "PORT" do
      port_number = String.slice(packet, -5..-2)
      TcpServer.start_link(port_number)
      :gen_tcp.send socket, "Started new server on port #{port_number}"
    else
      :gen_tcp.send socket, "Message received... \n"
    end
    IO.inspect packet, label: "incoming packet"
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:tcp_closed, socket}, state) do
    IO.inspect "Socket has been closed"
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:tcp_error, socket, reason}, state) do
    IO.inspect socket,label: "connection closed dut to #{reason}"
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong, or will this just not work for some reason that I'm not aware of?

(Code mostly pulled from https://medium.com/blackode/quick-easy-tcp-genserver-with-elixir-and-erlang-10189b25e221)

Comment: You've figured out the mistake already, so posting this as a comment: you can also remove the `"PORT "` prefix using pattern matching instead of `String.slice`: `def handle_info({ :tcp, socket, "PORT " <> port }, state)`.

Comment: That's super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the Erlang docs:

```
getserv(Port) when is_integer(Port) -> {ok, Port};
```

Looks like I needed this:

```
{port_number, _extra} = Integer.parse(String.slice(packet, -5..-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `port_number` to integer before passing to any `inet` functions.
I recommend to use [SockErl](https://github.com/pouriya-jahanbakhsh/sockerl)